# Zoom a custom user control on mouse move event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to zoom a custom usercontrol which contains a polygon, say paralellogram, which I created with the help of four points with X,Y coordinate but, when I try to zoom it on mouse move event, it stays at the same position and doesn't work out. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hard to tell what's not working when there is no code to look at.

Comment: Do you want the whole user control to be zoomed? and also post the code that you have already tried.

Comment: Got the trick... Can use the base property of that control to control the zoom of it. Many thanks :)